# Find rows where Column B is different but Column A is the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of unique identifiers for a person, and then a numerical code that corresponds to an action that needs to be taken on them.

I need a way to find which items in Column A have more than one value throughout Column B.

Example:

```
Column A    Column B
100         1
100         1
100         1
200         1
200         2
300         1
300         1
300         2
```

I need to be able to quickly determine that 200 and 300 have differing values in Column B, whereas 100 has all the same values. I just can't wrap my brain around how to do this and there are several hundred unique values in Column A.

Note that I am not an Excel guru by any means... I know enough to get by.

Can someone wiser than me please help? Thank you!

Comment: Highlight uniques?

Comment: I could write some vb.net code to do it but I have never messed with VBA so I don't know how to write it for that. If you want I can go ahead and write it and see if you or somebody can convert it to vba.

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)<>COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Returns `FALSE` for 100 in your example, and `TRUE` for 200 and 300.